# Post type specific upload folder in 3.5

Tags: uploads, media-settings

In 3.4 I used the following function to change image upload folder by post type.
[Different upload directory based on post type in a theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76895/different-upload-directory-based-on-post-type-in-a-theme)
Now it doesn't work anymore in 3.5. Do you have any idea how to replace this function in 3.5 version?

thanks

Comment: What is your research so far? What have you tried (aside from "those functions doesn't work anymore")? As you can read when hovering over the voting arrows or when you read the [faq], the site expects some research from your site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does. I had to do something similar just yesterday and worked out this solution. About the same as the linked solution, but with a bit more error checking.

```
<?php
add_filter('upload_dir', 'cgg_upload_dir');
function cgg_upload_dir($dir)
{
    // xxx Lots of $_REQUEST usage in here, not a great idea.

    // Are we where we want to be?
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['action']) || 'upload-attachment' !== $_REQUEST['action']) {
        return $dir;
    }

    // make sure we have a post ID
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['post_id'])) {
        return $dir;
    }

    // modify the path and url.
    $type = get_post_type($_REQUEST['post_id']);
    $uploads = apply_filters("{$type}_upload_directory", $type);
    $dir['path'] = path_join($dir['basedir'], $uploads);
    $dir['url'] = path_join($dir['baseurl'], $uploads);

    return $dir;
}
```