# Post Type Upload Directory - {post_type}_upload_dir filter

Tags: filters, media, uploads

I'm working with modifying the upload directory depending on which post type is being uploaded to. I've ran across this question: [Post type specific upload folder in 3.5](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83248/post-type-specific-upload-folder-in-3-5) and one of the lines confused me:

`$uploads = apply_filters("{$type}_upload_directory", $type);`

Where `$type` is the post type. They then go on to join the paths:

```
$dir['path'] = path_join($dir['basedir'], $uploads);
$dir['url'] = path_join($dir['baseurl'], $uploads);
```

Which works fine, you get the expected upload folder of `wp-content/uploads/post-type-name` but what does the `apply_filtes` achieve? It seems like I could just change that line to:

`$uploads = $type` or `$dir['path'] = path_join($dir['basedir'], $type);`

and I will still get the same folder structure, so what does the `apply_fitlers` portion actually achieve? I can't seem to find reference on the filter anywhere either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'apply_filters' runs the value through all of the other hooks / functions attached to it.  Try an experiment:

```
print_r( $type );
print_r( apply_filters("{$type}_upload_directory", $type) );
```

While you might, in your case, get the same thing - the apply_filters makes sure that any other plugins that try to influence this upload directory will still work.

Comment: Doing some research it doesn't even seem like there is a filter for `"{posttype}_upload_directory"` or a filter called `"upload_directory"` all I can find is `"upload_dir"` filter which leads me to believe that the filter is not needed. Do you have any links where the above filters exist in WordPress?

Comment: The filter is not needed, it's just added by the author for convenience to allow you to modify it later on from another plugin.