# How to store all featured images in a different folder?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I would like to store all featured images for my custom post type in a different directory/folder, & for all the other images used in the custom post type to be stored in the standard place. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there is a similar question here: [Post type specific upload folder in 3.5](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83248/post-type-specific-upload-folder-in-3-5)

Just add an IF case whenever the wanted post type is the one you want to be in another folder, if not, return the directory given by the filter.

Comment: This IMHO should be a comment.