# Set custom upload path for custom post type only?

Tags: custom-post-types, uploads

I have a custom post type of 'clients' and would like all images/files uploaded through the admin for these posts to go to a specific directory on my server, but everything else to stay as normal. Is this possible maybe using wp_upload_dir?

Answer (score 4):

You can add a filter to upload_dir.  Here is a simple class I wrote to do this for a project. Use the `protected $filter_path` variable to define the alternate uploads directory (*will be relative to wp-content/uploads)

```
class UGC_Attachment {
    protected $upload_dir;
    protected $upload_url;
    protected $filter_path = '/relative_path_from_wp-content/uploads';

    function __construct() {
        $dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $this->upload_dir = $dir['basedir'] . $this->filter_path;
        $this->upload_url = $dir['baseurl'] . $this->filter_path;
    }

    function upload_dir_filter( $upload ) {
        $target_path = $this->upload_dir;
        $target_url  = $this->upload_url;
        wp_mkdir_p( $target_path );
        $upload['path'] = $target_path;
        $upload['url']  = $target_url;

       return $upload;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
function prefix_upload_dir_filter( $post ) {
    if ( 'clients' != get_post_type( $post )
        return;
    $filter = new UGC_Attachment();
    return add_filter( 'upload_dir', array( &$filter, 'upload_dir_filter' );
}
```

The prefix_upload_dir_filter function would need to be attached to an action or filter with the $post object available or the $post ID.  You will need to do some more research to figure this part out or maybe someone else can chime in.  My usage was a complete custom image upload solution from the front end where I needed the publicly uploded images placed in a temp directory that could be cleaned out nightly via a cron job.

Comment: This looks perfect, will give it a try and report back later. Thanks Chris_O

Comment: I can't get this working. I got somewhere with this suggestion: [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77007/22448] but can't work out how to limit it to just one specific custom post type. Thanks for your help though Chris_O

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may do the trick, just change mycpt as you like

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'mycpt_uploaddir');

function mycpt_uploaddir( $param ){
    global $typenow;

    if ('mycpt' != $typenow)
        return $param;

    $mycpt = '/mycpt';

    $param['path'] = $param['path'] . $mycpt;
    $param['url'] = $param['url'] . $mycpt;
    return $param;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works quite well:

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'custom_prefix_upload_dir'  );

        function custom_prefix_upload_dir( $pathdata ) {
            global $current_user,$pagenow;
            if ( ( 'async-upload.php' == $pagenow || 'media-upload.php' == $pagenow ) && false !== strpos( wp_get_referer(),'post_type=clients' ) ) {
                $custom_dir = '/my_custom_uploads';
                if ( empty( $pathdata[ 'subdir' ] ) ) {
                    $pathdata[ 'path' ] = $pathdata[ 'path' ] . $custom_dir;
                    $pathdata[ 'url' ] = $pathdata[ 'url' ] . $custom_dir;
                    $pathdata[ 'subdir' ] = '/kanzu_intug';
                } else {
                    $new_subdir = $custom_dir . $pathdata[ 'subdir' ];

                    $pathdata[ 'path' ] = str_replace( $pathdata[ 'subdir' ], $new_subdir, $pathdata[ 'path' ] );
                    $pathdata[ 'url' ] = str_replace( $pathdata[ 'subdir' ], $new_subdir, $pathdata[ 'url' ] );
                    $pathdata[ 'subdir' ] = str_replace( $pathdata[ 'subdir' ], $new_subdir, $pathdata[ 'subdir' ] );
                }
            }

            return $pathdata;
        }
```