# Custom Upload Directory for Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, uploads

I have almost **64** different custom post type. Now I want to set custom media upload directory to them. I have 8array that contains 8custom post type each. For example:

```
array1 = array('type1','type2','type3','type4','type5','type6','type7','type8');

array2 = array('type1','type2','type3','type4','type5','type6','type7','type8');

array3 = array('type1','type2','type3','type4','type5','type6','type7','type8');

..

..

..

..

array8 = array('type1','type2','type3','type4','type5','type6','type7','type8');
```

Now I want to set custom media upload directory for all 8 array. I mean all post type of an array will get a common upload directory.

I found this tutorial [Different upload directory based on post type in a theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76895/different-upload-directory-based-on-post-type-in-a-theme) but its for individual custom post type.

Comment: So, modify the code you found. Altering that to work with multiple types should be trivial.

Comment: The linked question takes advantage of `get_post_type( $id )`, so you would need to test your array against that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll test and if face any problem I'll ask here for help.