# How to set up and use a custom upload directory for post type 'product'

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I try to set up a custom upload directory for just product images.

I use this code to create the folder 'product' in the uploads directory

```
function fcsp_type_upload_dir( $args ) {

// Get the current post_id
$id = ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ? $_REQUEST['post_id'] : '' );

if( $id ) {    
   // Set the new path depends on current post_type
   $newdir = '/' . get_post_type( $id );

   $args['path']    = str_replace( $args['subdir'], '', $args['path'] ); //remove default subdir
   $args['url']     = str_replace( $args['subdir'], '', $args['url'] );      
   $args['subdir']  = $newdir;
   $args['path']   .= $newdir; 
   $args['url']    .= $newdir; 
}
return $args;
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'fcsp_type_upload_dir' );
```

(Is from [Different upload directory based on post type in a theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76895/different-upload-directory-based-on-post-type-in-a-theme))

The directory is created fine but how can I get it right so it will store the product images in it?

I tried it with:

```
define( 'UPLOADS', trailingslashit( WP_CONTENT_DIR ) . '$args' );
```

The images, however, are still uploaded to the default upload directory i.e. `/uploads/2019/01`. What am I missing?

Comment: And what if you upload the image directly to media library and then assign it to product? Should it get moved?

Comment: No, it is not moved from `/uploads/2019/01` to `/uploads/product`. Was just thinking: I'm using the Media Cloud plugin to upload the images also to Amazon S3. In the end I just want to remove the uploaded images form the WordPress install after the upload to S3 is done. I can't remove them with the setting in the plugin because some mapping functions have to run first.

Answer (score -2):

```
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$uploads['basedir'].'/product/' /**** uplode product directory path ***/
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't the code from your answer just uploads everything to the /product/ folder? I need it only for the product images.